# Python Code Returning an Unrecognized Error

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm getting the following Syntax error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-3092209798892761>", line 6
    .agg(avg("sale_price").as("average_price"))
                            ^
```

with the following code:

```
t1.join(t2, Seq("make", "model"))\
  .filter(abs(t2("engine_size") - t1("engine_size")) <= BigDecimal("0.1"))\
  .groupBy("registration")\
  .agg(avg("sale_price").as("average_price"))
```

Can someone help shed some light on the error

Comment: as is a saved keyword in python, are you sure this is the function you wanted to run?

Comment: Hi @Mogi, thanks for reaching out. Yes I need it for the example should I'm trying to run. Also, can you let me know what the function Seq() does/mean?

Comment: And can you explain why I'm getting an syntax error?

Comment: For your information I got the code from here https://coxautomotivedatasolutions.github.io/datadriven/spark/data%20skew/joins/data_skew/

Comment: ahhhhh .... I just had a thought, may the code needs to written in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

`as` is a Python keyword - you can see it used in `import numpy as np`, for example.

This makes impossible to use it as a variable, function or method name.

You should use the equivalent `alias` when using Python:

```
t1.join(t2, Seq("make", "model"))\
  .filter(abs(t2("engine_size") - t1("engine_size")) <= BigDecimal("0.1"))\
  .groupBy("registration")\
  .agg(avg("sale_price").alias("average_price"))
```

Comment: Thierry, as regards your comments about alias in Python, that is what I was thinking. However, why couldn't I just us AS average_price? Also, can you let me know what Seq() does?

Comment: I'm now getting the error in Python 
NameError: name 't1' is not defined
May be I need to write this in Scala?

Comment: When I try to run the code in scala, as described in the link, get the following error:
`command-3092209798892765:2: error: not found: value abs
  .filter(abs(t2("engine_size") - t1("engine_size")) <= BigDecimal("0.1"))
          ^
command-3092209798892765:4: error: not found: value avg
  .agg(avg("sale_price").as("average_price")).collect()
       ^`

Comment: I think that for someone to help me they will need to take a look at the example from the link https://coxautomotivedatasolutions.github.io/datadriven/spark/data%20skew/joins/data_skew/

Comment: Please note that SO requests that questions be focused so that they  might have a chance to be useful to other users having the same or a very similar problem. As these are different questions, you should probably ask another question if you don't manage to solve them.

Comment: Thierry, thanks for the clarification. Basically, I'm just trying to get the code to work. I thought I could just get it work by running it in Python, but I think it needs to be run in Scala. I dont have much experience with Scala, therefore I thought it would be easier for someone to help get the code to run by referring to the link

Comment: ok, if I don't get any response, I'll close this question and ask again with help from someone experienced in Scala